# In shell script, execute a command only if the source is newer than the target

Tags: shell-script, files

I'm looking for a simplified version of this:

```
dep=0
if [ ! -e targetfile ]
then
    dep=1
elif [ targetfile -nt sourcefile ]
then
    dep=1
fi
if [ $dep -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Already up to date"
    exit 0
fi
```

It seems like there should be a command that tests for the existence and the age of the source file in a single statement.  Unfortunately `-nt` fails in bash if the target file doesn't exist at all.  I also need it to be compatible with `bash` and `dash` (which is why I'm not currently using `&&`).

Comment: BTW what is the problem with `&&`? It seems supported in `dash`, so `[ -f targetfile ]  && [ targetfile -ot sourcefile ] || echo "Already up to date"` should work. It actually does in my `dash`.

Comment: I'd been trying `[[ command1 && command2 ]]` syntax which doesn't seem to work in dash.

Comment: It helped me to remember that `/bin/[` actually exists, so the syntax should be process-oriented, not expression-oriented.

Comment: Did you mean `[ sourcefile -nt targetfile]`?  I can't understand the intent otherwise.

Comment: `[[` doesn't exist in dash, but `&&` does (outside the brackets). `-nt` isn't POSIX, but it's supported by dash as one of its few extensions. The usual way to do this (and the only practical way if you stick to POSIX) is to use make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work both in bash and dash:

```
if [ ! -e targetfile ] || [ targetfile -nt sourcefile ]
then
    echo "Already up to date"
    exit 0
fi
```

However, it seems like you want something like [make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/).

In `bash` you could even write
`make -f- <<<'targetfile: sourcefile ;' && exit 0`,
but the `<<<` syntax is bash specific, hence you need
`echo "targetfile: sourcefile ;" | make -f- && exit 0`
or simply a real Makefile. :)

Comment: I'm aware that make behaves like that, but it isn't trivial to dynamically write a make file and call make from a shell script.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller ? `make` takes the conventional `-` filename meaning stdin, the solution to OP's question as stated is `make -f- <<<'targetfile: sourcefile ;' && exit 0`

Comment: Ok, I take it back, that is trivial.  It would be ideal if michas could edit that into the answer.